# OpenGL Basic IBO/VBO Not Working

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, vertex-buffer

I've been following the tutorial listed [here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Tutorial1%3a_Rendering_shapes_with_glDrawRangeElements,_VAO,_VBO,_shaders_%28C++_/_freeGLUT%29).

I want to draw a single triangle using an Index Buffer Object, a Vertex Buffer Object, my own Vertex and Fragment Shader, and my own vertex structure.

My problem is that nothing shows up when I draw. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. My shaders work fine, I've tested them without the use of ibo/vbo's and they are fine.

Here is my code:

```
GLuint  vao[1], vbo_vertex[1], index_buffer[1];

typedef struct{
    GLfloat x,y,z;      // Vertex.
    GLfloat r,g,b;  // Colors.
} spicyVertex;

void initializeBuffers(){

    spicyVertex* simple_triangle = new spicyVertex[3];
    // V0 - bottom
    simple_triangle[0].x = 0.0f;
    simple_triangle[0].y = -0.5f;
    simple_triangle[0].z = 0.0f;
    simple_triangle[0].r = 1.0f;
    simple_triangle[0].g = 0.0f;
    simple_triangle[0].b = 0.0f;

    // V1 - top right
    simple_triangle[0].x = 0.5f;
    simple_triangle[0].y = 0.5f;
    simple_triangle[0].z = 0.0f;
    simple_triangle[0].r = 1.0f;
    simple_triangle[0].g = 0.0f;
    simple_triangle[0].b = 0.0f;

    // V2 - top left
    simple_triangle[0].x = -0.5f;
    simple_triangle[0].y = 0.5f;
    simple_triangle[0].z = 0.0f;
    simple_triangle[0].r = 1.0f;
    simple_triangle[0].g = 0.0f;
    simple_triangle[0].b = 0.0f;

    // Setup the vertex buffer data.
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo_vertex[0]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_vertex[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 3*sizeof(spicyVertex), simple_triangle, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    // Index setup
    GLushort *indices = new GLushort[3];
    indices[0]=0;
    indices[1]=1;
    indices[2]=2;
    glGenBuffers(1, &index_buffer[0]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, index_buffer[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 3*sizeof(GLushort), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // By this point all of our data should be on the graphics device.


    // VAO setup.
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao[0]);
    glBindVertexArray(vao[0]);

    // Bind the vertex buffer and setup pointers for the VAO.
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_vertex[0]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(spicyVertex), BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(spicyVertex), BUFFER_OFFSET(sizeof(spicyVertex)*3));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(3);

    // Bind the index buffeer for the VAO.
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, index_buffer[0]);

    // Cleanup.
    delete [] simple_triangle;
    delete [] indices;
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
}

void Draw_indexed_Vao(){
    glBindVertexArray(vao[0]);      // select first VAO
    glDrawRangeElements(GL_TRIANGLES,0, 3, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, NULL);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

static void display(void){
    glUseProgramObjectARB( programObj );

    Draw_indexed_Vao();
}
```

I'm not performing any view transformations, when I use more basic means of drawing everything shows up just fine right in front of the camera. I really do think it's something about the way I'm declaring these buffers.

**EDIT 1:** The application is double buffered.

**EDIT 2:** SOLVED. The 3 vertices V0, V1 and V2 were all modifying the same array element. As in, I wasn't using `simple_triangle[0]`,`simple_triangle[1]`, `simple_triangle[2]`, but that I was only working with `simple_triangle[0]`. Thank you again for catching my silly error.

Comment: Did you mean V1 and V2 to be simple_triangle[1] and simple_triangle[2]?

Comment: Gah! That solved it, thank you so very much. Small errors can get overlooked and cause so much trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an actual answer.

V1 and V2 are both modifying `simple_triangle[0]` so there is only ever one vertex.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to call `glFlush()` in order to push the contents of the buffers you've drawn to onto the screen.  Also, depending on whether you're using double buffering, the call required may be `glutSwapBuffers()` (if you're using GLUT) or some other swap call.

Comment: I've used glFlush() and haven't had any success, and I've been swapping the entire time.

Comment: Ah, ok, just didn't see it in the code provided.  Looks like loganfsmyth spotted the problem.  Glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna change

' gl**Vertex**AttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(spicyVertex), BUFFER_OFFSET(sizeof(spicyVertex)*3));'

to

'gl**Color**AttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(spicyVertex), BUFFER_OFFSET(sizeof(spicyVertex)*3));'

But I'm not 100% sure.